# Fade transition gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

In this new [example page](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) the image gallery has a moving transition coming from up. I would like to have a simple fade effect between images but I don't know where and what to change in the code. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't advise to mess with the original fancybox js file. You can always use your own custom fancybox script to override the default settings.

For the `fade` effect you want to have transitioning between gallery elements you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
  openEffect: 'fade',
  prevEffect: 'fade',
  nextEffect: 'fade'
 });
});
```

Comment: nothing !! The images effect is still like coming from up. I tried to change the fancybox.jsp and also the document code.$('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'fade',
    closeEffect : 'fade',

    prevEffect : 'fade',
    nextEffect : 'fade',

    closeBtn  : false,

    helpers : {
     title : {
      type : 'inside'
     },
     buttons : {}
    },

Comment: $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',

    prevEffect : 'fade',
    nextEffect : 'fade',

Answer (score 1):

You can change jquery.facybox.js as

```
   openEffect: 'fade', // 'elastic', 'fade' or 'none' line no 83
```

Or pass a argument on init

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
    prevEffect      : 'none',
    nextEffect      : 'none',
    openEffect:              'fade' ,   
    helpers     : { 
        title   : { type : 'inside' },
        buttons : {}
    }
});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check here: http://fancybox.net/api I guess the line you need is:

transitionIn, transitionOut             'fade'               The transition type. Can be set to 'elastic', 'fade' or 'none'

Comment: if you double check the question, he is actually talking about fancybox v2.x  ;)